# How do we deploy a trained tensorflow model on a mobile device?

Tags: tensorflow

One of the highlights of tensorflow appears to be "true portability" - seamless deployment of trained models across different platforms - especially running a trained model on a mobile device? Do you have an example or some tutorial that walks through how a trained tensorflow model can be packaged and executed within a mobile app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The TensorFlow repository includes an example Android application that uses the mobile device camera as a data source, and the Inception image classification model for inference. The source can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android), and the repository includes both the full source code and a link to download a [trained model](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip).

The model is the Inception model that won Imagenet’s Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge in 2014.